How to import files (not images) in components using paths defined in collection data?
I have an Astro collection called videos

Here is a collection schema:

import { defineCollection, z } from "astro:content";

const videoCollection = defineCollection({
  schema: ({ image }) => z.object({
    title: z.string(),
    video: z.string(),
    image: image(),
    imageAlt: z.string(),
  }),
});

export const collections = {
  videos: videoCollection,
};


Here's an example of how the collection is organised in the 'content' folder:

videos\
    entry1\
        index.md
        video.mp4
        image.jpg
    entry2\
        ...



Finally, here's index.md

---
title: Some title
video: ./video.mp4
image: ./image.jpg
imageAlt: Alt text
---

This is a description

Problem
I'd like to have an access to the video file in the component, that uses this collection entry data.

There is no problem with image field because I have used image() helper in schema. So the image file is imported at the time the collection is parsed. In my component, I receive data.image as object which I can use in image component as prop src. This works fine.

But I receive just a string from data.video. And I obviously can't use it as a prop src because it is just a string containing a relative path. So it is not an object referring to an imported file.  I think the same problem would apply to any other file types(pdf etc.)


---
import type { CollectionEntry } from 'astro:content';
import { Image } from 'astro:assets';

interface Props {
  entry: CollectionEntry<'videos'>;
}

const { entry } = Astro.props;
const { Content } = await entry.render();
---
<>
  <Image src={entry.data.image} alt={entry.data.alt} />
  
  <video>
    {/* WONT'T WORK */}
    <source src={entry.data.video} type="video/mp4" />
  </video>

  <Content />
</>

Possible solutions

I could use static assets in /public to store my videos, and pass to video field just an absolute path to the file, but I don't really like the idea, because

it's convenient to store all the files related to one collection entry together and you should think about the correct path when you define field in frontmatter, and
there is a problem with the browser cache, because when some static asset is updated, the filename remains the same (no new hash added).


I could use dynamic imports, but they have some limitations. For example, dynamic imports must end with a hard-coded file extension. And it looks really weird in code


    {/* will work but not a universal solution */}
    <source src={
      (
        await import(
        `../content/${entry.collection}/${entry.id.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/')}/${entry.data.src.slice(2, -4)}.mp4`
        )
      ).default
    } type="video/mp4" />

Any ideas on how to solve this better, like in a more convenient way, similar to working with images?
